# DynamicUpdate in Fluent NHibernate doesn't work

Tags: configuration, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

In my application there are many cases where I have to update one single property of an entity in the database. In the internet I've read that `DynamicUpdate()` should change the behaviour of Fluent NHibernate so it does only update the properties != null

So I wrote my mapping like this:

```
public class Building
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }

    public virtual int ConstructionPhase { get; set; }

    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    [some other properties]
}

public class BuildingMap : ClassMap<Building>, IMappedEntity
    {
        public BuildingMap()
        {
            DynamicUpdate();
            SelectBeforeUpdate();

            Id(x => x.Id);
            Map(x => x.ConstructionPhase);
            Map(x => x.Name);
            [some other properties]
        }
    }
```

But if I try to update an entity and leave the `name` property empty, the name is deleted in the database.

Do I have to configure Fluent NHibernate in an other way, or what's the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DynamicUpdate()` will instruct NHibernate to only save **properties that have changed** so loading the object, changing a single property and Flushing the session will only update the column that has changed.

Update: to update single properties without going to the database use hql

```
var affectedRows = session.CreateQuery("UPDATE MyEntity SET SomeProperty=:newValue WHERE Id=:id")
    .SetParameter("newValue", value)
    .SetParameter("id", id)
    .ExecuteUpdate();
```

Comment: But I thought Fluent NHibernate would ignore every property equal to null? If a user want to update one property, the form passes only the id of the entity and the new value for the property to my script.what can I do if I do not want to load the whole entity from the database to change this single property? It would be fine if I could simply send the entity to the database and leave everything empty that should not be changed.